# Trying to set up AWS IoT button for the first time: Please correct validation errors with your trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

Has anyone successfully set up their AWS IoT button?

When stepping through with default values I keep getting this message: `Please correct validation errors with your trigger.` But there are no validation errors on any of the setup pages, or the page with the error message.

I hate asking a broad question like this but it appears no one has ever had this error before.

Answer (score 3):

This has been driving me nuts for a week!

I got it to work by using **Custom IoT Rule** instead of **IoT Button** on the **IoT Type**.  The default rule name is iotbutton_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx and the default SQL statement is `SELECT * FROM 'iotbutton/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'` (xxx... = serial number).

Make sure you copy the policy from the sample code into the execution role - I know that has tripped up a lot of people.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error.  The cause turned out to be that I had multiple certificates associated with the button.  This was caused by me starting over again on the wizard, generating cert & key, loading cert & key again. While on the device itself this doesn't seem to be a problem, the result was that on AWS I had multiple certs associated to the device.

Within the AWS IoT Resources view I eventually managed to delete all resources. Took some fiddling to get certs detached and able to be deleted.  Once I deleted all resources I returned to the wizard, created yet another cert & key pair, pushed the Lambda code, and everything works.